# Alter rendered html in WooCommerce success message

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

After adding a product to the cart in WooCommmerce you get a notice saying:

“Product" has been added to your cart. View cart

The link element (View cart) is rendered first and the string  element (“Product" has been added to your cart.) second. I'd like to switch these element so the string is rendered first and link second.

HTML:

```
<div class="woocommerce-message" role="alert">
<a href="http://example.com/cart/" class="button wc-forward">View cart</a> “Happy Ninja” has been added to your cart.</div>
</div>
```

Tried tracking down the code but got stuck at:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/notices/success.php

Looking for a snippet to add to functions.php

Comment: Why would you do that? Because visually (on WooCommerce version 3.3.3), the "View Cart" link is displayed on the right hand side of the notice box, and the 'string element' on the left hand side. Unless of course, the default appearance/CSS is modified by the theme, a plugin, or you.

Comment: I think ux wise it's much better to have string first and link after. Works ok in desktop (yeah displays to the right) but in mobile it's harder to get it right. Wouldn't it be easier for all devices to just render link after?

Comment: Ok I'm not too expert in UX, so I'll skip answering the question. But I do have a PHP snippet you can try.

Comment: Please! Something from https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-cart-functions.php#L88 perhaps :)

Comment: Yes, we add a filter to the [wc_add_to_cart_message_html hook](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-cart-functions.php#L131). =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', function( $message ) {
    return preg_replace(
        // Or use ^(<a href=".+?" class="button wc-forward">.+?</a>) *(.+)
        '#^(<a href=".+?" class="button wc-forward">.+?</a>) +(.+)#',
        '$2 $1',
        trim( $message )
    );
} );
```

If no plugins (or if the theme doesn't) modify the default HTML markup (as you can see on [line #121](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-cart-functions.php#L121) and [line #123](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-cart-functions.php#L123)), the code above should work well.

[EDIT #3] Alternatively, you can completely re-generate the message/HTML, as in the following example:

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'my_wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 10, 2 );
function my_wc_add_to_cart_message_html( $message, $products ) {
    $titles = array();
    $count  = 0;

    foreach ( $products as $product_id => $qty ) {
        $titles[] = ( $qty > 1 ? absint( $qty ) . ' &times; ' : '' ) . sprintf( _x( '&ldquo;%s&rdquo;', 'Item name in quotes', 'woocommerce' ), strip_tags( get_the_title( $product_id ) ) );
        $count += $qty;
    }

    $titles     = array_filter( $titles );
    $added_text = sprintf( _n( '%s has been added to your cart.', '%s have been added to your cart.', $count, 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_list_of_items( $titles ) );

    // Output success messages - the "View cart" or "Continue shopping" link comes after the product link/info.
    if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) ) {
        $return_to = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', wc_get_raw_referer() ? wp_validate_redirect( wc_get_raw_referer(), false ) : wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) );
        $message   = sprintf( '%s <a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a>', esc_html( $added_text ), esc_url( $return_to ), esc_html__( 'Continue shopping', 'woocommerce' ) );
    } else {
        $message   = sprintf( '%s <a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a>', esc_html( $added_text ), esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ) ), esc_html__( 'View cart', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    return $message;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Brilliant! Edit #3 was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!